# Does Aperture have any known file management issues?

Tags: apple-aperture

I recently purchased Aperture 3 and am trying different things in order to find the best way to use it with my existing images. One thing I have noticed as I mess about with different file operations is that Aperture seems to "miss" files from time to time.

Some examples:

- I import from a directory containing 1214 pictures, Aperture imports 1091 of them.
- I import from a large directory tree like /year/month/event, and Aperture skips entire directories. (it imported every month except march and september).
- I try to move files from Aperture to a new location (relocate masters). Some files are still left in their old location.

Some of this can be explained by user mistakes; I initially didn't realize that rejected files were excluded by default, for example.

I am still trying to figure out if I am doing something wrong, but I would like to know if anyone else out there has noticed this behavior and if there is an explanation for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel a bit stupid to have to confess this but I think all my issues are explainable by user error. There is a (very small) chance that there are others as silly as myself out there so for their benefit I can summarize what I have found:

- Aperture seems to honor the "reject" flag during import even if it is set by *another* image management application. I have tried different tools over the years and apparently used the "reject" function in those.
- The reject flag seems to mean that Aperture ignores the file in all subsequent operations, export, relocate, consolidate etc. Which of course makes sense, really.
- The "don't import duplicates" works and if you have had less than stellar control of your workflow in the past you may have dupes in your image file hierarchy.
- When you let the finder count your image items, it includes the thm-files from video clips, Aperture doesn't, of course.
- And finally, the most embarrassing one - when you juggle different disks and versions of your image tree (you have backups of course) make sure you are actually importing from the same tree that you are looking at in the finder!

So with a red face I will now just trust Aperture to do the right thing and retire to be one with my shame...

Comment: +1 for the final point... :)
Who didn't do that mistake at least once? Don't worry pal

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen that behaviour myself, but do you have "Do not import duplicates" checked?  I don't know what the criteria for a duplicate is, but you might be running into it.  Try switching it off?

Comment: Thanks Scott, I was actually aware of this one but it's a good example of the kind of thing I'm asking for. (I actually discovered dupes I didn't know about thanks to this!)